# How do i add multiple conditions in an if statement in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm kind of new to JavaScript and all and I'm having trouble with how to add multiple conditions in an if statement. I wanted the if statement to do: "if 'this' and 'this' and 'this' is selected (I made a select tag so it is a drop down selection) then send the user to another page. I've search solutions but they're too complex for me right now as I'm still a beginner in JavaScript. Sorry if it is not explained well this is my first time making a question in this site. Thank You! Here's my code for the html if needed.

```
<h1>Clothes Picker</h1>
<form action="clothespicker.html" id="clothespicker">
<fieldset>
    <label for="place">Where are you going today?</label>
    <div>
        <select name="place" id="place">            
            <option value="Someone's House">Someone's House</option>
            <option value="Outdoors">Outdoors</option>
            <option value="Shopping">Shopping</option>
            <option value="Local Shopping">Local Shopping</option>
            <option value="Somewhere Special">Somewhere Special</option>
        </select>
    </div>

<label for="weather">What's the weather?</label>
    <div>
        <select name="weather" id="weather">
            <option value="Sunny" id="Sunny">Sunny</option>
            <option value="Cold">Cold</option>
            <option value="Rainy">Rainy</option>
            <option value="Cloudy">Cloudy</option>
        </select>
    </div>  

<label for="look">How do you want to look?</label>
    <div>
        <select name="look" id="look">
            <option value="Casual" id="Casual">Casual</option>
            <option value="Formal">Formal</option>
            <option value="I don't know">I don't know</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Pick My Clothes!" id="button"></div>
</fieldset>

</form>
```

Comment: You can do `if (conditionOne && conditionTwo && conditionThree) {}` The `&&` is how you say "and" in a javascript conditional statement

Comment: Also you should make a JavaScript file, then link it to the HTML you posted. Then you can use the `document.getElementById()` method to get references to HTML elements like `<option>`s. I think you can use `.value` to check the value of `options`

Comment: Ok! I'll try this method. Thank You.

Comment: @Tzvi2 So do I code "if(Outdoors && Cloudy && Formal){ Do this}"?

Comment: @Eli777Gaming remember to check out [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & always try to provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I made one condition for you take a look. My condition matched when you select "outdoors" from place, "Sunny" from weather and "casual" from look. If you have multiple conditions then you can else if after if condition

```html
<h1>Clothes Picker</h1>
<form action="clothespicker.html" id="clothespicker">
<fieldset>
    <label for="place">Where are you going today?</label>
    <div>
        <select name="place"  id="place">            
            <option value="Someone's House">Someone's House</option>
            <option value="Outdoors">Outdoors</option>
            <option value="Shopping">Shopping</option>
            <option value="Local Shopping">Local Shopping</option>
            <option value="Somewhere Special">Somewhere Special</option>
        </select>
    </div>

<label for="weather">What's the weather?</label>
    <div>
        <select name="weather" id="weather">
            <option value="Sunny" id="Sunny">Sunny</option>
            <option value="Cold">Cold</option>
            <option value="Rainy">Rainy</option>
            <option value="Cloudy">Cloudy</option>
        </select>
    </div>  

<label for="look">How do you want to look?</label>
    <div>
        <select name="look" id="look">
            <option value="Casual" id="Casual">Casual</option>
            <option value="Formal">Formal</option>
            <option value="I don't know">I don't know</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" onclick="myFunction()" value="Pick My Clothes!" id="button">
</fieldset>
<p id="demo"></p>
</form>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var place = document.getElementById("place").value;
  var weather = document.getElementById("weather").value;
  var look = document.getElementById("look").value;
  if(place == "Outdoors" && weather == "Sunny" && look == "Casual")
  {
    //your condition here
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Condition Matched";
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This seemed to do the job! Thanks!

Comment: What does document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Condition Matched"; mean?

Comment: remove it write your own condition. I wrote it just to notify you that condition is true you can also use alert() or your own condition

Comment: Alright! Thank you everything works now. Thanks for the help everybody.